# Call an external API in Anylogic

Tags: java, anylogic

Is it possible to create an API in Anylogic, which calls a weather API to get data like temperature, sunrise etc.?

I have an existing API call in Python which saves my needed data in an Excel file. Can Anylogic start my external Python .exe or .py to refresh the values and update them to Anylogic at specific model time?

Or in other way: Is it possible to generate a Java Class or Java Interface which an API call? How I can call Java classes/ interfaces in Anylogic to run?

Answer (score 0):

You sure can! Here's a link to a model that includes a few example calls to external APIs.

[Example API Calls from AnyLogic (downloadable model)](https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/a303dbaf-bee1-45b5-8a2e-13f0f7134ca4?mode=SETTINGS)

You may also be interested in Pypeline, it's a custom AnyLogic library created by Tyler Wolfeadam that includes a block which can be used to run Python code from within Anylogic. Here's a link to the github repository: [Pypeline Github](https://github.com/t-wolfeadam/AnyLogic-Pypeline)

**Note:** Extra effort is sometimes required to make API calls and Pypeline work from AnyLogic cloud.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have any problem to make an HTTP request from Anylogic, the first thing you have to do to make an HTTP request is importing all the right libraries that offers native Java on the model properties:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
```

Next, create this function, if you want to make an HTTP request that gives a response in JSON format this is the way to go.

```
 try {
        
        String url = "https://www.example.com";

        // Open the connection
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        
        // Method
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        // Response
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("Código de respuesta: " + responseCode);

        // Read the response
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
        }
        reader.close();

        
        System.out.println("Response:");
        System.out.println(response.toString());

        // Close the connection
        connection.disconnect();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```